# Url Parameters not able to recieved in component in react Js when Passing Props with Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, react-router, url-routing

I am passing a props( props of all the details of items from which I will select a product baased on the ID received from URL ) into ItemDetails component and I want to display product according to the item Id which is passed through the URL. unfortunately I am unable to use 
`this.pops.match.params`
 in ItemDetails components I am not understanding why its not reviving the URL parameters can anyone help?

This is how I am passing props to the Component.
`<Route exact path='/item/:id' component={()=><ItemDetail itemsData={this.props.itemsData} />} />`

Comment: Can you please post `<ItemDetail>` component definition as well? Thanks!

Comment: click [here](https://hastebin.com/tipobezoya.js) to go to ItemDetails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I see. One of the issues is that on yow route you have it like: `item/:id` which I believe `:id` is dynamic. Now u see it, if you are not going to receive the same exact value. The `exact` should be remove.

Other thing that puzzles me is the way you set the `component` prop, why is it an arrow function and not a reference `component={ItemDetail}`. If you want to use it as an arrow function the callback gets a parameter call `props` or any name you want, but it comes the with the props. So you need to spread them:

```js
<Route path=“my-path” component={props=> <ItemDetail {...props} />
```

Comment: Actually I am learning react Js so in one video I saw like that sending component using arrow function so that we can also send the props needed to It. About the code you gave I am not understanding it  can you please explain how what its doing ?

Comment: take a look a this. it has basically all react-router-dom api: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params